# Error while uploading Flutter App to App Store: Non-public API usage

Tags: flutter, app-store, hybrid

I am new in Flutter Development and i have developed an app with Webview.
I have upload an apk on Google Play Store that is accepted but for App Store it shows some error.

Please find below error,

> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
>   symbols in Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: _ptrace. If method
>   names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above,
>   altering your method names will help prevent this app from being
>   flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of
>   the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included
>   with your app. If so, they must be removed.

For this error i have search many things but i am unable found any solution for this.
So please any one who is capable of solving this please help me to resolve this.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you are submitting the debug version to the AppStore, Flutter team recommends you to first run

```
flutter build ios --release
```

before archiving your app in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are submitting a release build with `flutter build ios --release`

If that's not the problem here you could find similar problems related:

[flutter build ios --release may use a debug Flutter.framework by mistake](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37850)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I updated my Mac to 10.15(Catalina), while the update my cocoapods installation wasn't there. So whenever I try to upload using the command `flutter build ios --release` and archiving it. Apple sent me the same email you received.

You can install cocoapods using the following commands.

step 1 Open terminal

step 2 command: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

step 3 set your project path on the terminal.

step 4 command: `pod init`

I hope it helps.